# phase shift between two images (matrices)

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to find the phase shift between two 100x100 matrices, s and p. To start with I'm using two sine waves (2D) slightly shifted. I manage to compute the correct amplitude spectrum (using the Fourier Transform of the cross correlation between s and p) but the phase value at the peaks is not the one that I have set. I'm not using cpsd because I did not manage to understand the correct way to use it for 2D matrices. The manual is very confusing and I couldn't get any help online.

When I do the same procedure for 1D sine waves, using cpsd or fft of xcorr employing the welch method, I get both the amplitude and phase right. I suppose that conceptually I'm doing the right thing, but there's sth about how to get the phase shift between two matrices that is bugging me.

I really would appreciate any tips on how to compute the phase shift between matrices. Some real piece of code would be lovely.

thank you in advance for your time